# Send markdown text with telegram bot (telegraf), nodejs

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

How to send markdown text by telegram bot using telegraf library on nodejs?

Comment: Hi there, looks like you're new to StackOverflow. Welcome aboard! When asking a question we expect that you provide an example of what you have tried to solve the problem with. Please provide a [mcve] & check out the [How to Ask Page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info on how to create an awesome question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
const token = 'YOUR TOKEN';
const Telegraf = require('telegraf')
const extra = require('telegraf/extra')
const markup = extra.markdown()

const telegram = new Telegraf(token)

telegram.telegram.sendMessage('there chat id', 'your message', markup)
```

Comment: this one is old old old, not working not

Answer (score 14):

With **telegraf v4.3.0**, I got it working using the following code:

```
const bot = new Telegraf(token);
bot.telegram.sendMessage('my chat id', 'my text', { parse_mode: 'MarkdownV2' });
```

Comment: Can be used in more simplest way: `ctx.replyWithMarkdownV2(message)`, your code will be under the hood.

Answer (score 6):

```
ctx.replyWithMarkdown(MESSAGE)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the context object `ctx` in imported modules to reply and don't want to import Telegraf, then you can use:

```js
ctx.reply('some _text_', {reply_markup: 'markdown'})
```